# How to check If my PC was exploited after apt exploit?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, apt, security, aptitude

I used

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

before I read https://www.debian.org/security/2019/dsa-4371
Is there a way to check if my PC got exploited/hacked/virused ?

Comment: Make a note of all packages installed, and compare the checksum of the locally-installed package file to the checksum of a copy of the package in a known-good repository.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Is there a guide, article or documentation where I can read how to do this ?

Comment: try running chkrootkit

Comment: Suggestion : install apparmor from debian stretch backports. That'll save you from being possible victim of future security flaw.